# How to show Locations those are within 2 Miles?

Tags: android, gps, location

How to show Locations those are within 2 miles from my current Location, i am using below code which allow me to get distance of few locations from my current location in Miles...

but now i want to know, which condition i need to write if i want my app to show locations within 2 miles ?

```
public void distanceBetweenTwoLocations() {
    Location currentLocation = new Location("");
    currentLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    currentLocation.setLongitude(longitude);

    for (int i = 0; i < actorsList.size(); i++) {
        locations = (Locations) actorsList.get(i);
        Location destinationLocation = new Location(" ");
        destinationLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(actorsList.get(i).getLatitude()));
        destinationLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(actorsList.get(i).getLongitude()));
        double inMeters = currentLocation.distanceTo(destinationLocation);
        double inKms = inMeters / 1000;             
        double inMiles = inKms * 0.000621371;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        locations.setDistance(df.format(inMiles));
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare your `inMiles` object and need to set adapter again.

try with the following code :

```
public void distanceBetweenTwoLocations() {
    Location currentLocation = new Location("");
    currentLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    currentLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
    ArrayList<Locations> myNewLocationList = new ArrayList<Locations>;
    for (int i = 0; i < actorsList.size(); i++) {
        locations = (Locations) actorsList.get(i);
        Location destinationLocation = new Location(" ");
        destinationLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(actorsList.get(i).getLatitude()));
        destinationLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(actorsList.get(i).getLongitude()));
        double inMeters = currentLocation.distanceTo(destinationLocation);
        double inKms = inMeters / 1000;             
        double inMiles = inKms * 0.000621371;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        locations.setDistance(df.format(inMiles));

        if (inMiles < 2) // Comapring Miles whether it is in 2 mile or not
            myNewLocationList.add(mLocations); // adding it to new List
    }
    // Setting adapter again with new list having below 2 mile distance
    adapter = new LocationsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.adapter_locations, myNewLocationList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: such a nice solution :) a great programmer